# Convert Case - Convert upper case to lower case in specific csv column

Tags: powershell

I need help to convert all values from specific csv column  (Name) into lower case, using powershell script.

```
    Change ID       Name                ITSM_Info
183115          ZYXjjjKKK           Possible CRQ
183115          ZYXasdasdj          Possible CRQ
183115          ZYsdajjKKK          Possible CRQ
183115          ZYXjjjKKK           Possible CRQ
183115          abcjKKK             Possible CRQ
183115          ZY1222KKK           Possible CRQ
186081          ZY123qwerK          Possible CRQ
```

Expected output

```
  Change ID     Name                ITSM_Info
    183115          zyxjjjkkk           Possible CRQ
    183115          zyxasdasdj          Possible CRQ
    183115          zysdajjkkk          Possible CRQ
    183115          zyxjjjkkk           Possible CRQ
    183115          abcjkkk             Possible CRQ
    183115          zy1222kkk           Possible CRQ
    186081          zy123qwerk          Possible CRQ
```

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSV values are all read in as strings by `Import-Csv`, and `[string]` already has a [`ToLower()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolower) we can use for this!

```
$lowerCased = Import-Csv .\path\to.csv |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Name = $_.Name.ToLower()
  $_
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried something like this `$lowerCased = Import-Csv "D:\code\Blackout.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Name = $_.Name.ToLower()
  $_
} | Export-Csv -Path  "D:\code\Blackout.csv  -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation` but it is not working

Comment: @majan What happens? Empty `blackout.csv` file? File created but `Name` column still upper case? Errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me,

```
$lower = Import-Csv "D:\CRQ.csv"  -Delimiter ';' 
$lower | ForEach-Object { 

                      $_.'Name' = $_.Name.ToLower()

     } 
$lower | 
Export-Csv -Path "D:\CRQ_tmp.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: So basically, you forgot to mention the delimiter in your CSV file is a semicolon `;`, not the default comma `,`